# How to import a txt file with single quote mark in a variable and another in another variable

Tags: sas

I have a file `prova.txt`, which contains:

```
001|PROVA|MILANO|1000
002|'80S WERE GREAT|FORLI'|1100
003|'80S WERE GREAT|ROMA|1110
```

I'm importing it as a SAS dataset with this code:

```
libname mylib "/my/lib"; 

data prova;
infile '/my/lib/prova.txt' 
    dlm='|' dsd lrecl=50 truncover;
format 
    codice  $3.
    nome    $20.    
    luogo   $20.
    importo 4.
    ;
input 
    codice  :$3.
    nome    :$20.
    luogo   :$20.       
    importo :4.
    ;
run;
```

And I get this result:

[image]

As you can see, the first and the third records are imported well, whereas the second has `nome` = `80S WERE GREAT|FORLI` and the rest of the variable are a mess.

How can I correctly import this file?

P.S. = the single quote marks in the file are correct. `FORLI'` is name of a town in Italy and there is a firm whose name begins with `'80`. Of course these are not the real names, but the real case is exactly like that. I need to import the variables with a quote marks in their content.

Comment: do you need the quotes? or can delete them?

Comment: @AlexeySigida Better if I can keep them.

Comment: @AlexeySigida If there is no other solution, I could substitute them with spaces...

Comment: Do you ever have any fields that contain the actual delimiter character, `|`, in them?  If not then remove the DSD option.

Comment: @Tom Yes, removing DSD works, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DSD` and `DLM` cause the single quoted (`'`) embedded delimiter (`|`) to be part of the data value.

Remove the `DSD` options and the delimiter will not be considered 'value embedded' and thus become a value separator for the example case of `002|'80S WERE GREAT|FORLI'|1100`

The format statement implicitly defines a variable value type and length if it contains the first mention of a variable in the step.  Because of that you can simplify the `input` statement to be just a list of the variables:

```
filename sample 'c:\temp\sample.txt';
data _null_;
  file sample;
  input;
  put _infile_;
datalines;
001|PROVA|MILANO|1000
002|'80S WERE GREAT|FORLI'|1100
003|'80S WERE GREAT|ROMA|1110
;

data want;
data prova;
infile sample dlm='|' lrecl=50 truncover;
format 
    codice  $3.
    nome    $20.    
    luogo   $20.
    importo 4.
    ;
input 
    codice  
    nome    
    luogo   
    importo 
    ;

putlog _infile_;
run;

proc print;
run;
```

[image]

Comment: Relying on FORMAT statement to define variables only works if it is the first place that the variable is used. That is because it is taking advantage of a side effect that it will force SAS to define the variable and SAS will use the format widths to guess how you wanted them defined.  Also using the format statement has the additional effect of attaching those format permanently to the variables.  So if this dataset is merged with another where the same variable has a different length you can get in situations where the format width is different than the variable length.