# How to import a txt file with single quote mark in a variable and another in another variable, when there are also variables with null values

Tags: sas

This is a follow-up of my previous question:
[How to import a txt file with single quote mark in a variable and another in another variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60301822/how-to-import-a-txt-file-with-single-quote-mark-in-a-variable-and-another-in-ano).

The solution there works perfectly until there is not a variable whose values could be null.

In this latter case, I get:

```
filename sample 'c:\temp\sample.txt';
data _null_;
  file sample;
  input;
  put _infile_;
datalines;
001|This variable could be null|PROVA|MILANO|1000
002||'80S WERE GREAT|FORLI'|1100
003||'80S WERE GREAT|ROMA|1110
;

data want;
data prova;
infile sample dlm='|' lrecl=50 truncover;
format 
    codice  $3.
    could_be_null    $20.    
    nome    $20.    
    luogo   $20.
    importo 4.
    ;
input 
    codice  
    could_be_null
    nome    
    luogo   
    importo 
    ;

putlog _infile_;
run;

proc print;
run;
```

[image]

Is it possible to correctly load a file like the one in the example directly in SAS, without manually modifying the original .txt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to pre-process the file to fix the issue.

If you add quotes around the values then you will not have the problem.

```
002||"'80S WERE GREAT"|"FORLI'"|1100
```

**IF** you **know** that none of the values contain the delimiter then adding a space before every delimiter

```
002 | |'80S WERE GREAT |FORLI' |1100
```

will let you read it without the DSD option.

If lines are shorter than 32K bytes then it can be done in the same step that reads the data.

```
data test2 ;
  infile sample dlm='|' truncover ;
  input @;
  _infile_ = tranwrd(_infile_,'|',' |');
  input (var1-var5) (:$40.);
run;

proc print;
run;
```

Results:

```
Obs    var1               var2                var3                var4     var5

 1     001     This variable could be null    PROVA              MILANO    1000
 2     002                                    '80S WERE GREAT    FORLI'    1100
 3     003                                    '80S WERE GREAT    ROMA      1110
```

One way to test if you have the issue is to make sure each line has the right number of fields.

```
filename sample temp;
options parmcards=sample;
parmcards;
001|This variable could be null|PROVA|MILANO|1000
002||'80S WERE GREAT|FORLI'|1100
003||'80S WERE GREAT|ROMA|1110
;

data _null_;
  infile sample dsd end=eof;
  if eof then do;
    call symputx('nfound',nfound);
    putlog / 'Found ' nfound :comma11. 
           'problem lines out of ' _n_ :comma11. 'lines.'
    ;
  end;
  input;
  retain expect nfound;
  words=countw(_infile_,'|','qm');
  if _n_=1 then expect=words;
  else if expect ne words then do;
    nfound+1;
    if nfound <= 10 then do; 
       putlog (_n_ expect words) (=) ;
       list;
    end;
  end;
run;
```

Example Results:

```
_N_=2 expect=5 words=4
RULE:     ----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5----+----6----+----7----+----8
2         002||'80S WERE GREAT|FORLI'|1100 32
_N_=3 expect=5 words=3
3         003||'80S WERE GREAT|ROMA|1110 30

Found 2 problem lines out of 4 lines.
```

**PS** Go tell SAS to enhance their delimited file processing:  https://communities.sas.com/t5/SASware-Ballot-Ideas/Enhancements-to-INFILE-FILE-to-handle-delimited-file-variations/idi-p/435977

Comment: It works perfectly with the sample file but I have some problems with the actual file. I'll try again on Monday and ask a new question, if I can't solve the problem. As for telling SAS, it doesn't seem your suggestions had a big success :) I think SAS will be soon substituted by some other more up-to-date language, if they don't become more flexible...

Comment: Another trick to try is to change all single quotes to some other character that never appears in the file.  You can then loop through each character variable and change them back again once you are able to read the file into a dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `DSD` option to your `INFILE` statement.

https://support.sas.com/techsup/technote/ts673.pdf

> **DSD (delimiter-sensitive data) option**—Specifies that SAS should treat
>   delimiters within a data value as character data when the delimiters
>   and the data value are enclosed in quotation marks. As a result, SAS
>   does not split the string into multiple variables and the quotation
>   marks are removed before the variable is stored. When the DSD option
>   is specified and SAS encounters consecutive delimiters, the software
>   treats those delimiters as missing values. You can change the default
>   delimiter for the DSD option with the DELIMTER= option.

Comment: No, sorry, if add DSD option, I get what I explained in my previous question, linked to this one. Try and see...